# How do I use grunt plugins programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, gruntjs

I'd like to use the [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) plugin as well as others in one of my own Node.js projects. The only problem is I can't figure out how to interact with them programmatically. Here's an example:

```
grunt.config.init({
  jshint: {
    all: ['asourcefile.js']
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

grunt.task.run('jshint');
```

Grunt loads the `jshint` plugin ok and it seems like it can find my task (using a made up name throws an error), it just doesn't seem to actually execute it.

Where am I going wrong and is this even the best way to interact with a grunt plugin programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of gruntplugins are just wrappers around existing Node.js libraries. [JSHint's, for example](https://npmjs.org/package/jshint). If you're writing a Node.js app, don't use the grunt wrappers:

```
var jshint = require('jshint');
// ...
```

Comment: Ah good point. The plugin I was really interested in was [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and it looks like that uses [Gaze](https://github.com/shama/gaze), so I'll just require that instead. Thanks for the help.